# Mark "trips" in time series using: groupby idcolumn and cumsum of timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe that looks roughly like this:

```
    carid                 timestamp             speed       brake,....
0   00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18 03:46:15   NaN 0.0
1   00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18 03:46:20   0.842667    0.5
2   00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18 03:46:25   6.704000    0.5
3   00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18 03:46:30   11.746000   NaN
4   00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18 03:46:35   NaN 0.5
5   00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18 03:46:40   16.961000   NaN
6   00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-19 03:46:45   11.832000   0.5
7   00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-19 03:46:50   22.741333   NaN
```

The dataframe is sorted by carid, then by timestamp. I am looking to add a column that adds a trip ID so that for every row that has the same car id, and the previous row differs by no more than 5 seconds from the previous, that they get the same ID; rows 0 - 6 should all get ID 0, rows 6 - 7 should get ID 1, etc.

Something like

```
(df.timestamp.diff(1).astype(int) > 5000000000).astype(int).cumsum()
```

seems to do the job if there were only one carid in the frame, but I don't know how to differentiate it on the carid.

edit: as @RafaelC pointed out, my data sample was inconsistent with my description, I've updated the table.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match your description.. especially because 1. row 0 differs a minute from row 1 and 2. how 6 gets id 0 or id 1? and 3. row 3-4 differs more than 5 sec

Comment: And should IDs reset for different carids?

Comment: @RafaelC, my apologies, I pasted the table wrong it seems, now corrected (I think).

Comment: @AntonvBR the IDs should run on for different car ids, not reset.

Comment: @retorquere Look at my answer and see if anything matches what you want.

Comment: I think the function you are looking for is .groupby("carid").transform( <your function> )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in unique IDs you could use the | ('or') operator with two conds *(this was something I together with someone else answered somewhere else but I can't find it)*

```
import pandas as pd 

data = '''\
carid                 timestamp             speed       brake
00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18T03:45:15   NaN         0.0
00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18T03:46:15   0.842667    0.5
00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18T03:46:20   6.704000    0.5
00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18T03:46:25   11.746000   NaN
00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18T03:46:35   NaN         0.5
00056f66da29e6b615aa  2017-07-18T03:46:40   16.961000   NaN
00056f66da29e6b615ab  2017-07-19T03:46:50   11.832000   0.5
00056f66da29e6b615ab  2017-07-19T03:46:55   22.741333   NaN'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
```

**Alternative 1**: No reset

```
cond1 = df.timestamp.diff().dt.total_seconds().gt(5)
cond2 = df.carid != df.carid.shift(1)

df['uid'] = (cond1 | cond2).cumsum()

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
                  carid           timestamp      speed  brake  uid
0  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:45:15        NaN    0.0    1
1  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:46:15   0.842667    0.5    2
2  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:46:20   6.704000    0.5    2
3  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:46:25  11.746000    NaN    2
4  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:46:35        NaN    0.5    3
5  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:46:40  16.961000    NaN    3
6  00056f66da29e6b615ab 2017-07-19 03:46:50  11.832000    0.5    4
7  00056f66da29e6b615ab 2017-07-19 03:46:55  22.741333    NaN    4
```

**Alternative 2**: Reset  *(Tried to improve the code (shorten), but head is stuck)*

```
y = []
for _, dfx in df.groupby('carid'):
    x = dfx.timestamp.diff().dt.total_seconds().gt(5).cumsum() +1
    y.extend(x)

df['uid'] = y

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
                  carid           timestamp      speed  brake  uid
0  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:45:15        NaN    0.0    1
1  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:46:15   0.842667    0.5    2
2  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:46:20   6.704000    0.5    2
3  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:46:25  11.746000    NaN    2
4  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:46:35        NaN    0.5    3
5  00056f66da29e6b615aa 2017-07-18 03:46:40  16.961000    NaN    3
6  00056f66da29e6b615ab 2017-07-19 03:46:50  11.832000    0.5    1
7  00056f66da29e6b615ab 2017-07-19 03:46:55  22.741333    NaN    1
```

Comment: Super awesome all you guys! Yes, the reset example does exactly what I want, *plus* it gives me more means to clean up this blasted dataset; looks like I'll have to test for "gap > 5 seconds and speed lower than 30", but that's easy now (and apologies for the bad example data).